# When are local variables in a function scope destroyed?

Tags: c++, function, c++17

After a function is called, when the local (non-static) objects will be destroyed has been vague to me, especially after C++17 where prvalue is redefined. So I decide to ask this question.

---

(In C++14 and earlier)

Assume there is no optimization, consider the following toy code:

```cpp
class Y
{
public:
    ~Y() { cout << "quitting f()\n"; }
};

class X
{
public:
    X& operator=(const X& x)
    {
        cout << "assignment\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

X f()
{
    X x;
    Y y;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    x = f();
}
```

The outputs are as follows:

```
quitting f()
assignment
```

**Question 1:**

In my current understanding, the local variables of `f()` are destroyed immediately after the returned temporary is created. May I ask if this is true?

---

(In C++17 and newer)

Consider the following toy code:

```cpp
class Z { };

class Ya
{
public:
    ~Ya() { cout << "quitting f1()\n"; }
};

class Yb
{
public:
    ~Yb() { cout << "quitting f2()\n"; }
};

class X
{
public:
    X() {}
    X(Z z) { cout << "constructing X\n"; }

    X& operator=(const X& x)
    {
        cout << "assignment\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

X f1()
{
    Z z;
    Ya y;
    return X(z);
}

X f2()
{
    Yb y;
    return f1();
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    x = f2();
}
```

The outputs are as follows:

```
constructing X
quitting f1()
quitting f2()
assignment
```

In my current understanding, `X(z)` is a prvalue which is used to initialize the prvalue represented by `f1()`, which is then used to initialize the prvalue represented by `f2()`. The prvalue represented by `f2()` is then materialized into a temporary which is then used in the copy assignment.

If my understanding to **question 1** is correct, I would guess that the local variables `z` and `y` are destroyed immediately after the initialization of the prvalue represented by `f1()`. Assume this is true, there is a problem: before the prvalue represented by `f2()` is materialized, there is NO object constructed from `X(z)` exists, so how could the materialized temporary be created from `X(z)` at the point when `z` is already destroyed?

**Question 2:**

As a result, my guess is that the local variables of `f1()` are destroyed after the prvalue represented by `f2()` is materialized (or if the prvalue is used to initialize a variable, had we written `X x = f2();` instead). May I ask if this is true?

Comment: At the end of the scope it's defined in. The next matching }

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thank you for your comment. I think then my question is down to how prvalue works so that all the prvalue passing stuffs are done before the evaluation of the `return` statement is finished? Sorry I'm not even sure if this is a well-formed question... I don't understand prvalue well...

Comment: My understanding is that local variables on the stack are always destroyed after reaching the end of a function in the reverse order that they are declared. Use gdb to convince yourself, you can set break points at the destructors of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be answered with a slightly more detailed example.  Here is code that traces when every object is constructed and destroyed:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>

// Compile-time string suitable as a non-type template argument.
template<size_t N>
struct fixed_string {
    char value[N];
    consteval fixed_string(const char (&str)[N]) { std::copy_n(str, N, value); }
};

template<fixed_string Name>
class tracer {
  std::ostream &out() const { return std::cout << Name.value << " "; }
public:
  tracer() { out() << "default constructed\n"; }
  tracer(const tracer &) { out() << "copy constructed\n"; }
  tracer(tracer &&) { out() << "move constructed\n"; }
  template<typename T> tracer(T t) {
    out() << "template constructed [" << typeid(T).name() << "]\n";
  }
  ~tracer() { out() << "destroyed\n"; }
  tracer &operator=(const tracer &) {
    out() << "copy assigned\n"; return *this;
  }
  tracer &operator=(tracer &&) { out() << "move assigned\n"; return *this; }
};

tracer<"X">
f1()
{
  tracer<"Z"> z;
  tracer<"==== f1 temp"> y;
  return {z};
}

tracer<"X">
f2()
{
  tracer<"==== f2 temp"> y;
  return f1();
}

int
main()
{
  tracer<"X"> x = f2();
}
```

The output (with C++20) is as follows:

```
==== f2 temp default constructed
Z default constructed
==== f1 temp default constructed
Z copy constructed
X template constructed [6tracerIXtl12fixed_stringILm2EEtlA2_cLc90EEEEE]
Z destroyed
==== f1 temp destroyed
Z destroyed
==== f2 temp destroyed
X destroyed
```

So you can see that only one `X` is ever created, but that `X` is created before the `Z` it is constructed from is destroyed.  How does that happen?  Well, in the implementation you can think of the location in which to construct the `X` being passed as a kind of implicit argument to the functions that return a prvalue, so that the `X` is constructed inside `f2`, but it is located in `main`'s stack.

Your example is slightly more complicated, but the same phenomenon is happening:

```
int
main()
{
  tracer<"X"> x;
  x = f2();
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
X default constructed
==== f2 temp default constructed
Z default constructed
==== f1 temp default constructed
Z copy constructed
X template constructed [6tracerIXtl12fixed_stringILm2EEtlA2_cLc90EEEEE]
Z destroyed
==== f1 temp destroyed
Z destroyed
==== f2 temp destroyed
X move assigned
X destroyed
X destroyed
```

So now obviously we have two `X`'s, the one called `x`, and the temporary one that is materialized to pass into `x`'s move assignment operator.  However, the temporary `X` is created on `main`'s stack, and its lifetime is the full expression, so if there were more code in `main`, the temporary `X` would be destroyed at the semicolon after the assignment, rather than at `main`'s closing brace.