# is destructor called when active stack popped that contain the definition of object?

Tags: c++

I put just print a simple print statement at the constructor and the destructor.

```
class Complex {
public:
    Complex() {
        cout << "default ctor called\n";
    }
    ~Complex() {
        cout << "dctor called\n";
    }
}
Complex getComplex() {
    Complex temp;
    cout << "----inside function----\n";
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    Complex c = getComplex();
    cout << "----inside main----\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**expected output:**

```
----inside function----
default ctor called
destructor called
----inside main----
```

**Actual output**

```
----inside function----
default ctor called
----inside main----
destructor called
```

Why when the function returned the destructor didn't call at function?
Actually, it doesn't make sense because I learned that when declaring any variable at a function, it ends when the function is returned.

Comment: Where does `c` go out of scope? (the `c` in `main()`?)

Comment: what about the destructor in a function, **when is it called?** @David C. Rankin

Comment: @Run [Function local variables are destroyed immediately after the function's return value is initialized.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73481454/12002570)